# mysql: get minimum date when goal is reached

Tags: mysql

I hope this description is clear:

I have a table with this fields:

| user_id | order_id | creation_date | fractions | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u.id_1 | o.id_1 | date_1 | 0.0024 | Some name |
| u.id_2 | o.id_2 | date_2 | 0.0053 | some name |

I want another field which tells me for every user_id which is the minimum date when it get at least 0.05 fractions.

I have this query

```
SELECT r.user_id as user_id,
       r.id as order_id,
       r.created_at as creation_date,
       r.fraction as fractions,
       r.mining_name as name,
       SUM(r.fraction) OVER (PARTITION BY r.user_id ORDER BY r.created_at) as growing_sum,
       CASE WHEN SUM(r.fraction) OVER (PARTITION BY r.user_id ORDER BY r.created_at) >=0.05 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS isInClub500
FROM yield_mining_rent r
ORDER BY user_id, creation_date
```

which tells me if tells me a cumulative sum and also if I'm over 0.5 fractions but I also would like a single field.

I know that I could do this if I use CTE like this:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT r.user_id                                                           as user_id,
                    r.id                                                                as order_id,
                    r.created_at                                                        as creation_date,
                    r.fraction                                                          as fractions,
                    r.mining_name                                                       as name,
                    SUM(r.fraction) OVER (PARTITION BY r.user_id ORDER BY r.created_at) as growing_sum,
                    CASE
                        WHEN SUM(r.fraction) OVER (PARTITION BY r.user_id ORDER BY r.created_at) >= 0.05 THEN TRUE
                        ELSE FALSE END                                                  AS isInClub500
             FROM yield_mining_rent r
             ORDER BY user_id, creation_date
)
SELECT user_id,
       min(creation_date)
FROM CTE
WHERE isInClub500 = true
GROUP BY user_id
```

but my question is: is there a way to get this without CTE?
Thank you so much

EDIT:
Here's [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hQrufGeO) so things might be easier

Comment: Please post a fiddle for it.  It will make it easier for users top respond.